# how to handle space in sending json parameters to server in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am sending data to the server it is going successful but response coming with %20 at the space in data what I have sent to server here is the code I am using

```
  NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.me911.com/new/miphone3/android_edithealth.php?profile_id=%@&health_condition=%@&health_insurance_provider=%@&primary_physician_name=%@&primary_physician_phone=%@&last_physical=%ld&blood_type=%@&organ_donor=%@",profileId,txthospital.text,textinsurence.text,txtprimary.text,txtphone.text,dateInMillis,questionNo,textorgan.text];

  str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];

  NSLog(@"Healthinfo URL:  %@",str);

  NSMutableURLRequest *dataRqst = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:str] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:30.0];

  [dataRqst setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];    
   NSString *stringBoundary = @"0xKhTmLbOuNdArY---This_Is_ThE_BoUnDaRyy---pqo";

   NSString *headerBoundary = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",stringBoundary];

  [dataRqst addValue:headerBoundary forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

   NSMutableData *postBody = [NSMutableData data];    
   [dataRqst setHTTPBody:postBody];

   NSHTTPURLResponse *dataresponse =[[NSHTTPURLResponse alloc] init];
   NSError* error = [[NSError alloc] init] ;

//synchronous filling of data from HTTP POST response

   NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:dataRqst returningResponse:&dataresponse error:&error];

//convert data into string

   NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[responseData bytes] length:[responseData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

   NSLog(@"responseString %@ ",responseString);

   if (responseString == NULL)
   {        
    NSDictionary *infoDic = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"There was a small problem",
                   @"title",
                   @"The network doesn't seem to be responding, please try again.",
                   @"message",
                   @"OK",
                   @"cancel",
                   @"1",
                   @"tag",nil,
                   @"delegate", nil];

      [CommonFunctions performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(showAlertWithInfo:) withObject:infoDic waitUntilDone:NO];

   }    
  else
  {

    NSDictionary *jsonResponse = [responseString JSONValue];

    if ([jsonResponse objectForKey:@"error"]){
        NSLog(@"response %@",jsonResponse);            
    }
    else{

    }
    NSMutableArray *dataresponse=[jsonResponse valueForKey:@"success"];

    if ([jsonResponse objectForKey:@"success"])
    {            
        NSLog(@"Array response %@",dataresponse);
    }        
}
```

**And this is web service**

> :http://anaadit.net/miphone3/android_edithealth.php?profile_id=287&health_condition=palo%20Alto%20Veterans%20Hospital%20&health_insurance_provider=Blue%20Cross&primary_physician_name=Dr.Akki&primary_physician_phone=6504935000&last_physical=-57600&blood_type=7&organ_donor=No

Here I am sending data in textfield in like **guru prasad** but response getting like this **guru%20prasad**.

So please correct me where am I going wrong .

thanks in advance

Comment: What will be the expected result? Now something like "{ "error": true}"

Comment: no like this " {"error": 1}"

Comment: The above code is working successful but it is saved in database like this: guru%20prasad,but i am sent guru prasad

Comment: whats wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a number of issues.

In order to create a URL with query params, I recommend to use the utility class `NSURLComponents` (see [Apple documentation: NSURLComponents](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLComponents_class/index.html)).

Composing a POST request whose content type is "multipart/formdata"  is quite error prone. If you absolutely have to compose such a request I very *strongly* recommend to use a Network Library, for example [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking).

On the other hand, using a POST request whose Content-Type is `application/json` is very easy to setup, especially with [NSURLSession](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/) and friends.

You can find specific solutions for any of the suggested approaches mentioned above on SO, too.

Answer (score 0):

Its seems there is some problem in parsing data, the space are replaced with %20...It seems you are using NSURL Connection for making API Calls.

Use AFNetworking for making API Calls, the response data will automatically come in JSON format and you can initialize Dictionary from same.

Please find below link for AFNetworking:
https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking

Answer (score 0):

Please use "AFNetworking" and the code will be:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    NSDictionary *parameters =  @{@"profile_id": @"287", @"health_condition": @"palo Alto Veterans Hospital", @"health_insurance_provider": @"Blue Cross",
                                  @"primary_physician_name":@"Dr.Akki",
                                  @"primary_physician_phone":@"6504935000",
                                  @"last_physical":@"-57600",
                                  @"blood_type":@"7",
                                  @"organ_donor":@"No"};

    [manager POST:@"http://anaadit.net/miphone3/android_edithealth.php" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
```

Please try the above code. I think this will help you.

Comment: i am trying your code it's working but space is not coming between text what i am sent